# node.js not writing JSON to file correctly

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am writing JSON objects to a file that are streaming from the twitter api.  They log to the console correctly and look like JSON objects; however, when I use the command:

```
fs.appendFile("./tweets.json", tweet)
```

All that writes to the file is the following:

```
[object Object]
```

What is going on here?  When I write the object tweet to console, this is the output:

```
 { created_at: 'Tue Mar 17 22:12:41 +0000 2015',
     id: 577955743997018100,
     id_str: '577955743997018112',
     text: 

  ......tons more stuff....

  filter_level: 'low',
  lang: 'en',
  timestamp_ms: '1426639434951' }
```

What is [object Object] and why is it writing that?

Comment: If you see `[object Object]`  in your file then `tweet`  is not a string containing data in the `JSON` format, but a regular javascript object. And the console output : `{ created_at: 'Tue Mar 17 22:12:41 +0000 2015',`  shows clearly that it is not `JSON`. In a `JSON` formatted string the `key`  needs to be quoted with double-quotes.

Answer (score 7):

Change this line

```
fs.appendFile("./tweets.json", tweet);
```

to

```
fs.appendFile("./tweets.json", JSON.stringify(tweet, null, ' '));
```

This is because appendFile will call `toString()` which will print what you see, so you need to turn the object into a JSON string.

The second two arguments to `stringify` will pretty print the JSON object so that you can look at it and edit it manually. If you prefer the compact format, simply leave those out.

Answer (score 1):

The `fs.appendFile` expects a string. But you give it an object. All you need to do is to convert the object to string. Call the `JSON.stringify`.

```
fs.appendFile("./tweets.json", JSON.stringify(tweet))
```

If `fs.appendFile` does not receive a string then it tries to convert the argument to string. And does it badly.